# redefine ng-model using ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So i have a type ahead that users can select options from after typing into the form. If the search data exists, the description of the data gets automatically filled into a textarea. However, if the search data does not exist, the description box gets automatically filled with the search data, which is not what i want, as it should be a empty string since it  doesn't exist.

```
<input type="text" required class="form-control form-control-modal" ng-model="newTreatment.async_selected_treatment" typeahead="treatment as treatment.service for treatment in searchTreatments($viewValue)" typeahead-editable="false" typeahead-on-select="searchTreatment($item)" focus="true" placeholder="CPT Code" >

<textarea class="form-control required form-control-modal" rows="3" ng-if="newTreatment.async_selected_treatment.id == 'null'" ng-model="newTreatment.async_selected_treatment.description" placeholder="Add a Description" ></textarea>
```

i wrote the ng-if, but its not working as intended. I need to basically check if the

```
newTreatment.async_selected_treatment.id
```

is null(since it doesnt exist in the backend), then i need

```
newTreatment.async_selected_treatment.description
```

to return nothing

pictures for reference

I'm open to other suggestions/ideas on tackling this issue

Working

[image]
Not working
[image]

Comment: well, if it actually does not exist you should check `=== undefined`, if it is in fact null you should check using `=== null`. Also, it is almost always better to use `===` instead of `===`, especially when checking for null, because JS are evil masters and a lot of stuff can lead to false when just using `==`.

Comment: Also, I didn't quite understand what you are trying to achieve here. If the `ng-if` is hidden - Your descriptions does not sound like that is what you want

Comment: could you please share the angularjs code and template so that we can find what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `typeahead-editable="false"` and add `ng-blur` directive  please see here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/vcJsfd5ZuwYvirpIGAOx?p=preview

HTML:

```
Model: {{selected | json}}
```

```
<input type="text" typeahead-editable="false"  ng-blur="clear()" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">
```

js:

$scope.clear = function() {

```
if ($scope.selected === undefined) {

  $scope.selected = '';

}
```

Comment: Great example, but the problem with mine is that its 2 different models. The second one is binded to the first

Comment: using plunkr to replicate is too hard, ill give you gist for you to take a look
https://gist.github.com/gwong89/b0ccc7ea2133da8915b0